# Generate Avro Schema File and Store in HDFS

Tags: centos, hdfs, avro

I'm using avro tools to generate a schema file from an avro file in HDFS and dump it to the Linux file system using this command:

```
hadoop jar /usr/bin/Avro/avro-tools-1.8.1.jar getschema /dw/hpm/ap_drg/ap_drg.avro > usr/bin/StageSchema/ap_drg.avsc
```

This works great and gets me the file I need. However; I would like the schema file to be in HDFS and not the Linux file system. How can I change this command to accomplish this? Is there another way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Played around for a bit and finally figured out something that worked:

```
hadoop jar /usr/bin/Avro/avro-tools-1.8.1.jar getschema /dw/hpm/ap_drg/ap_drg.avro | hadoop fs -put -f - /dw/schemas/hpm/ap_drg/ap_drg.avsc
```

This will extract an Avro schema from an Avro file on hdfs and write to an Avro schema file in hdfs. The `-f` will make sure any existing schema file will be overwritten.