# Hive Table Creation based on file structure

Tags: hadoop, hive

i have one doubt, is there any way in HIVE which create table during load to hive warehouse or external table.

As i know hive is based on Schema On Read. so table structure must sync with file structure. but if file size is huge and we don't know its structure for example columns and their datatypes.

Than how to load those file to hive table.

so in short how to load file from HDFS to HIVE Table without knowing its schema structure.

New to Hive, Pardon if my understanding is wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using sqoop you can **create hive table** while importing data.

Please refer to [this](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_create_hive_table_literal) link to create hive table while importing data

(or)

if you have imported data in AVRO format then you can generate avro schema by using 
**/usr/bin/Avro/avro-tools-*.jar** then use the generated avro schema while creating table in hive then hive uses the schema and reads the data from HDFS.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39667843/generate-avro-schema-file-and-store-in-hdfs) link to extract schema from avro data file

(or)

While importing data using sqoop --as-avrodatefile then sqoop creates .avsc file with schema in it, so we can use this .avsc file creating the table.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE avro_tbl
  ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
  STORED as INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
  LOCATION '<hdfs-location>'
  TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='<schema-file>');
```

(or)

By using NiFi to import data NiFi pulls data in avro format by using **ExtractAvroMetadata** processor we can extract the avro schema and store into HDFS and create table by using this avro schema.

If you want to create table in ORC format then by using **ConvertAvroToOrc** processor adds **hive.ddl** attribute to the flowfile as we can execute the ddl statement to create orc table in hive.

Comment: (or) Kafka HDFS Connect with Hive integration (supports at least Avro)

Comment: @Shu: Thanks a lot